# C# code to create a memory leak.

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I'd like to write a simple C# program / console application to create a slow and controlled memory leak. I want the program to slowly eat up system memory. I need this for something else that I am testing.

It was suggested to me to use:

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numbytes)
```

attached to a timer.

Here is the code I tried to implement:

```
class Program
{
    static Timer timer = new Timer();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        start_timer();
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hglobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglobal);

        Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Console.WriteLine(proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
    }

    private static void start_timer()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

The output seems to indicated that memory is still being managed and garbage collection is doing its job. Can someone help me out with this? My goal is to indeed create a memory leak and use up system resources. Someone please suggest what is wrong with my code, or an alternative, better option.

Comment: When you say "memory leak" do you just mean memory allocations that the GC won't free up? Why not just push data into a referenced List?

Comment: Create an infinite loop that does some computation.

Comment: Won't calling `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` deallocate the memory you just allocated?

Comment: I'm curious what the application of this is. It sounds intriguing.

Comment: I think Jacob's suggestion is the best. Just allocate a `List<T>` then add objects to it in a loop. You can have really granular control also because say, if you want to add 16 bytes per second you could define a class with 3 int's (assuming we're on 32 bit Windows, 12 bytes for the object 4 for the reference) then put a 1000 ms sleep in your loop.

Comment: Nothing is working!! I tried a loop. I tried a recursive Fibonacci algorithm, I tried the list idea, I tried commenting out Marshal.FreeHGlobal. The output and task manager are all telling me that the memory is being managed! Is it even possible to create a memory leak in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 64 bit?!?

Comment: @Zolt you could try writing some code in an `unsafe` block.

Answer (score 3):

For a leak, you need to actually leak memory. Right now, you do not leak any, because you free it:

```
    IntPtr hglobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
    // DO NOT DO THIS IF YOU WANT A LEAK: Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglobal);
```

Comment: So I commented out `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglobal);` and there still no leak. The output shows that when proc.PrivateMemorySize64 gets as high as 22585344, but then it drops back down to a lower number and grows back to 22585344. This just goes on and on. Also, task manager shows that system memory use is not increasing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Zolt is 22585344 the size of the processes virtual address space?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a controlled memory leak for a failure mode test case for an app running in Azure App Services.

This is a drop in MVC class.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using log4net;

namespace foo.FooApp.MVC.UI.Controllers
{
    [Route("memleak")]
    public class MemLeakController : Controller
    {
        /*
         * This code is a simple drop in solution that can be placed into a MVC controller application and will create a controlled memory leak.
         * It provides three endpoints
         * /InitMem - This is the initial page that provides a link to start the memory leak
         * /RunMem - This page takes two parameters and will create a controlled memory leak.
         * * Parameter 1: MemToAllocate, this is the amount of memory to consume per each iteration.
         * * Parameter 2: MemToConsume, This is the number of allocation iterations.
         * /ClearMem - This will reset (clear) any memory allocations.
         * It was determined using a List of Bytes for memory allocation was a better solution than some of the other techniques, for example: Marshal.AllocHGlobal and static event EventHandler.
         * For measuring memory allocation it was determined that using GC.GetTotalMemory rather proc.PrivateMemorySize64 provided more accurate results.
         * This test will eventually cause an System.OutOfMemoryException. The Test can be reset by clicking on the clear memory link
         * As of now App Services will fail with out of memory after about 3.4 GB of memory allocation.
         */
        private static readonly ILog Logger =
            LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType);

        private const string MemClearHtml = "<ul><li><a href=\"/memleak/ClearMem\")\">"
                                            + "<span>Reset Memory Leak Test</span>"
                                            + "</a></li></ul>";

        private const string MemRunHtml = "<ul><li><a href=\"/memleak/RunMem?MemToConsume=5&MemToAllocate=100\")\">"
                                          + "<span>Run Memory Leak Test</span>"
                                          + "</a></li></ul>";

        private const string TextareaHeader = "<textarea id=\"foo\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"50\">";
        private const string TextareaFooter = "</textarea>";
        private static long _memToAllocate = 1000000 * 100; // 100 MB
        private static int _memToConsume = 5; // * _memToAllocate = 500 MB
        private static long _lastMem;

        // ReSharper disable once CollectionNeverQueried.Local
        private static readonly List<byte[]> ListToConsume = new List<byte[]>();

        /*
         * Initial page to start the memory leak test
         * Endpoint URI: /memleak
         */
        [HttpGet]
        public void Index()
        {
            Logger.Info("Init MEM " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
            Response.Output.Write("Start Memory Leak Test {0} <br><br>", MemRunHtml);
            Response.Output.Write("Current Memory Bytes: {0} <br>", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
            Response.Output.Write("Current Memory MB:    {0} <br><br>",
                GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024));
        }

        /*
         * Main page for submitting memory allocation
         * Endpoint URI: /memleak/RunMem?MemToConsume=5&MemToAllocate=100
         */
        public void RunMem()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString.ToString()))
                {
                    var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
                    _memToAllocate = long.Parse(nameValueCollection["MemToAllocate"]) * 1000000; // 1 MB
                    _memToConsume = int.Parse(nameValueCollection["MemToConsume"]);
                }

                Response.Output.Write("Memory Leak Test {0} <br><br>", MemClearHtml);

                Response.Output.Write("Memory Leak Test {0} {1:HH:mm:ss} <br>", "Start:", DateTime.Now);
                Response.Output.Write("Current Memory Bytes: {0} <br>", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
                Response.Output.Write("Current Memory MB:    {0} <br><br>",
                    GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024));
                Logger.Info("Start MEM " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));

                Response.Output.Write(TextareaHeader);
                for (var i = 0; i < _memToConsume; i++)
                {
                    ListToConsume.Add(new byte[_memToAllocate]);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
                    if (_lastMem == mem) continue;
                    Response.Output.Write("Current Memory Bytes: {0} \n", mem);
                    Response.Output.Write("Current Memory MB:    {0} \n", mem / (1024 * 1024));
                    Logger.Info("Start MEM " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
                    _lastMem = mem;
                }

                Response.Output.Write(TextareaFooter);

                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Response.Output.Write("<br><br>Current Memory Bytes: {0} <br>", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
                Response.Output.Write("Current Memory MB:    {0} <br>",
                    GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024));
                Response.Output.Write("Memory Leak Test {0} {1:HH:mm:ss} <br><br><br>", "End:", DateTime.Now);

                Response.Output.Write("Consume Next {0} {1} ",
                    _memToAllocate * _memToConsume / (1024 * 1024) + " MB",
                    MemRunHtml);
                Logger.Info("Start MEM " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.Message);
                LogError(ex);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Page to reset (clear) the memory allocation
         * Endpoint URI: /memleak/ClearMem
         */
        public void ClearMem()
        {
            Response.Output.Write("Start Memory Overload Test {0} <br><br>", MemRunHtml);
            ListToConsume.Clear();
            GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Response.Output.Write("<br>Current Memory Bytes: {0} <br>", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
            Response.Output.Write("Current Memory MB:    {0} <br>",
                GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024));
            Response.Output.Write("Memory Overload {0} {1:HH:mm:ss} <br>", "End:", DateTime.Now);
            Logger.Info("Stop MEM " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        }

        private void LogError(Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication)).Error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not an actual memory leak because, even if you set the controller as singleton, at any point you can clear that `ListToConsume` which will make the GC collect it back...